# ExtJs How can I add column support to an expander plugin?

Tags: gridview, extjs, sencha-touch, store, sencha-architect

I have a dynamically generated grid with an expander plugin.

The contents of the expanded area are set with an Ext.Template.

```
body: {
    tpl: '<div>This is a custom tpl. It is not affected by grid columns.</div>'        
}
```

Is there any way I can bind the expanded content area with the grid columns/model? Meaning, can I make the content of the expander plugin follow the structure of the grid, and have custom values to each column?

A grouper to the grid's store has a functionality similar of what I need, but I can not add custom values as I could with the expander plugin. (See example screenshot below)

[imgur example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lL274.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement a rowwidget with a grid in it, [check this example](https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/examples/kitchensink/?classic#row-widget-grid) or [a tree grid](https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/examples/kitchensink/?classic#tree-grid)

Comment: That's a subgrid. I need it to be the same grid as the parent grid, with the same columns reacting to each other etc

Comment: Then probably a tree grid could help?

Comment: That might actually work, I didn't think about it. Thanks!

Comment: Glad that it helped, I've updated the answer as well.